# Issues with EXIF Library in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, exif-js

I have the code below, and no matter what I try I literally cannot get the exif data to show up I have no clue what is going on. This code is taken straight from the github of the exif-js library: https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

```js
window.onload = getExif;

function getExif() {
  var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
  EXIF.getData(img1, function() {
    var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
    var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
    var makeAndModel = document.getElementById("makeAndModel");
    makeAndModel.innerHTML = `${make} ${model}`;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/exif-js"></script>
<img src="https://2.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TS1200x900~sample_galleries/0861943200/2984823081.jpg" id="img1" style="max-width: 200px;" />
<pre>Make and model: <span id="makeAndModel"></span></pre>
<br/>
<pre id="allMetaDataSpan"></pre>
<br/>
```

When I open my HTML file in chrome (not been published yet so opening directly from my computer) it just shows this:

I tried every single solution available on the internet but code that works for others won't work for me (ex. https://awik.io/extract-gps-location-exif-data-photos-using-javascript/)

Comment: Kindly, edit your question and add code instead of images! Also, add error from console (if any).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What debugging have you tried? Eg there is an obvious answer but you didn't say if you've checked that - are you sure your jpg has Exif data?  Or maybe it just doesn't have those fields - have you tried to retrieve all Exif data, as shown in the docs?  Does the example page included in the lib work?  Are there any errors on your devtools console?

Comment: check the code is running, also check for errors in the browser *developer* tools console  - also, have you considered that the image has no EXIF at all, or no Make/Model tags?

Comment: I made a snippet with the correct CDN libraries. It gives CORS errors here and on jsfiddle - try it from your computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works, but only if the server the image is from the same origin as your script OR that the image server supports CORS

Here is a working version from my server with the image from the same origin

https://plungjan.name/SO/exif/

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const getExif = (id) => {
    let img1 = document.getElementById(id);
    EXIF.getData(img1, function() {
      console.log("EXIF running"); // 
      var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
      var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
      makeAndModel.innerHTML = `${make} ${model}`;
    });
  };
  const makeAndModel = document.getElementById("makeAndModel");
  getExif("img1")
});
```